# Laravel File not found at path (again)

Tags: laravel

So, I've already dug through the questions here about this, but still can't seem to figure it out.

Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

```
$imageName = $thishire->color_image;

$path = public_path('/img/colorImages/' . $imageName);

$file = Storage::get(public_path('/img/colorImages/'. $imageName));

$file->move($path, public_path('/img/uploads'));
```

The 3rd line is throwing an error:

"File not found at path: Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GT Laravel/public/img/colorImages/l18Ow1uVBqhReGqW7lWjanp2vT5bOAKt8pylnmmb.jpg"

But that is the correct path, so I'm super confused.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do `Storage::get(public_path('/img/colorImages/'. $imageName))`.

`Storage::get()` is relative to the storage disk root.

If you use the default storage configuration, then your storage root path is `storage_path('app')`, said otherwise `/path/to/your/project/storage/app`.

This is what's happening:

```php
Storage::get(public_path('/img/colorImages/'. $imageName));
// looking into /path/to/your/project/storage/app/path/to/your/project/public/img/colorImages 

// which is obviously wrong
```

What you should do instead:

1. Store your public files in the `storage/app/public` directory
2. Use the `php artisan storage:link` command to create a symlink between `public` and `storage/app/public`. If you are not familiar with this concept, it'll create a small file into your `public` directory which is a shortcut to the `storage/app/public` directory. More about this here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

For instance, with a file named `helloworld.jpg` and located in `storage/app/public/users/8/helloworld.jpg`, you can get it by doing:

```php
Storage::disk('public')->get('users/8/helloworld.jpg');
// or Storage::get('public/users/8/helloworld.jpg');
```

I know it can be confusing at first. This is a quick tip to "know where you are and what your are looking at". Use `Storage::path()`:

```php
dd(Storage::path(public_path('/img/colorImages/'. $imageName)));
// you'll see the problem
```

Comment: still digesting your post, but the one problem I have is this:  "Store your public files in the storage/app/public directory".   That means A LOT of re-coding which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: @Colin I understand it is not the answer you expected, but unfortunately this is why it wasn't working :( It is possible to work directly with the `public` directory but you must know it is not a good practice and you'll have to reconfigure some Laravel config (take a look at `config/filesystem.php`). However, this is out of the scope of this question. If the answer helped you understand what was wrong, you should validate it and ask another question with your specific "new" problem. It's the best way to find someone to help you. Wish you good luck!

Answer (score 1):

don't forget `public` meaning access storage but by created `symlink`

I think you should be store image in your path before getting it by using

```
Storage::put(public_path('/img/colorImages/'), $imageName);
```

and you can check documentation from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
 $imageName = $thishire->color_image;
            
  $old = public_path('/img/colorImages/'.$imageName);
  $new = public_path('/img/uploads/'.$imageName);
            
  rename($old, $new);
```